# Peer Pressure Badge

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes, badges

Exactly how many down votes do you need, to get Peer Pressure Badge?
I have seen a few articles that say -3 does not mean 3 down votes. How many downvotes do you need to receive the badge?

Comment: At least 3: *Delete own post with score of -3 or lower*, ie: 3 more than the number the number of upvotes.

Comment: you can now delete that post.

Comment: @Oighea unfortunately i cant because someone answered it so i can't delete the post :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [**Peer Pressure  Badges**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) :-> 
>   Delete own post with score of -3 or lower.

- Bronze Badge awarded once
- Delete one of your own posts that has a score of negative three or lower at the time of deletion
- Posts that you own but are not self deleted do not count.

[image]

for more information read this post [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)